# Gatsby - Load page specific styles

Tags: gatsby

Gatsby build is bundling all styles into one file, I want to bundle only those styles which are used on that specific page so we can reduce the bundle size.

Comment: with module css I think you can name your css files like `myfile.module.css` to automatically have this behavior